# How get images in storage with Laravel API -> error 404

Tags: jquery, laravel, api, handlebars.js

I'm using: Laravel 7, jQuery, Handlebars

Here's the flow I'd like to implement:

- with jQuery I make a get API call to Laravel with the last 10 Post

`$.get('api/get-posts').done(...)`

- the API controller return the last 10 post with images

```
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(10)->get();

        foreach ($posts as $post)
        {
            $post['member'] = $post->member;
            $post['tags'] = $post->tags;
            $post['imgs'] = $post->imgs;
        }
        
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'results' => $posts
        ]);
    }
```

and that works cause the json return the images correct link:

`"img": "post-img/BLux1Wp3AIuKuMGyNhQdhtzUH9eH0EnBlVn07FxB.png",`

the img is stored in `public/storage/post-img/...` (i've created the symlink)

- with Handlebars template I'd like to print images in the post card, like this:

```
background-image: url(@{{ cover }});
```

- but when i open the page i get error404 http://localhost:8000/post-img/BLux1Wp3AIuKuMGyNhQdhtzUH9eH0EnBlVn07FxB.png **404 (Not Found)**

If i go to Source I don't found the folder post-img with the images.

I tried with Storage::download and other things.

I found nothing on docs.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: it should be  http://localhost:8000/storage/post-img/BLux1Wp3AIuKuMGyNhQdhtzUH9eH0EnBlVn07FxB.png. you have missed storage from url

Comment: There was the problem! Thanks